Return whole child DTO inside parentDto
I have class student(Parent class) and school(child class) DTO.
When i try to print parent class i am not getting child class with all fileds.
Class Student{
  private String name;
  private  School school;

}

Class School{
  private String schoolName;
  private String address;

}

while returning Student.builder().build(). without including specially school field in builder    return Student.builder().school(School.builder().build()).build()
I getting output:
{name: null, school:null}

I want :
{name:null , school: {schoolName: null, address: null}}


Assuming you use builder generated by the Lombok library.
Since Lombok v1.16.16 it is possible to define default field values for instances created with builder. To do that, use the @Builder.Default annotation on fields:
@Data
@Builder
class Student {
    @Builder.Default
    private School school = new School();
}

Documentation on annotation usage can be found here.
